# Detect characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string, performance

I'm playing with ruby on codewars. The task is to create a method that accepts a string and returns a string of length 26 of `1`s and `0`s. The 26 characters of the string correspond to each letter of the alphabet (upper or lower case) and is `1` if the letter is in the string, `0` if not. If an `a` or an `A` is in the string, the first character of the returned string is `1` otherwise `0`, if `b` or `B` is, the second is `1`, and so on. For instance:

```
change('a   **&  bZ') # => '11000000000000000000000001'
```

Solutions:

```
def change input 
  ('a'..'z').to_a.join.gsub(/[#{a.scan(/[a-zA-Z]/).uniq.join}]/i,'1').gsub(/\D/,'0')
end
```

vs.

```
def change input 
  ('a'..'z').map { |letter| input.downcase.include?(letter) ? '1' : '0' }.join
end
```

How can I tell which solution is more optimal? There can be more optimal ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `n` be the number of letters in the input and `m` be the number of letters in the alphabet.

---

```
input.scan(/[a-zA-Z]/).uniq.join
```

is `O(n) + O(n) + O(n)`. Fortunately, you are doing this only once (when what the pattern to `gsub` is evaluated) Therefore, your complexity adds up to `2*O(m) + 3*O(n) + O(m)` = `O(max(n, m))`.

---

On the other hand,

```
input.downcase.include?(letter)
```

is `O(n)`, but it is executed for each letter in the alphabet, leaving you with `O(m*n) + O(m)` = `O(m*n)`.

---

Therefore, the first solution is asymptotically better, as `O(max(n, m)) < O(m*n)`.

That is unless you consider the number of letters in the alphabet a *small constant*, in which case they are both `O(n)` and it's just a matter of benchmarking.

You can see that both are linear:

[image: With regex; first solution]

[image: No regex; second solution]

Running *100_000* iterations on a random *1000* letter string gave the following results (using *cruby 2.2.2*):

```
       user     system      total        real
  36.160000   0.000000  36.160000 ( 36.182512)
   3.910000   0.000000   3.910000 (  3.915191)
```

So in practice, the second solution is far superior.

It is also way more readable.

Comment: Furthermore, it is even better if `downcase` is moved to outside of the `map` block.

Comment: "[U]nless you consider the number of letters in the alphabet a small constant"--You should consider this to be the case.

Comment: @sawa, I was just making a note in case we want to look at the algorithms in a more abstract manner. For example, if we are using mandarin, or all UTF-8 characters, or an imaginary encoding.

Comment: I get what you mean, but even so, it remains a constant.

Comment: Nice tests. I didn't expect such big difference in performance. Did you benchmarked two full versions of #change method. Or pieces of them?

Comment: @Ann, the full versions.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question (which one is the most efficient) but an idea that uses binary arithmetic and the ascii table:

```
def change input
    res = 0
    input.each_byte { |c|
        res |= c.between?(97,122) ? 1<<(122-c) : c.between?(65,90) ? 1<<(90-c) : 0
    }
    "%026b" % res
end

s = "Portez ce vieux whisky au juge blond qui fume"
puts change s
```

This code uses the ascii ranges 97-122 for lower-case letters and 65-90 for upper case letters. `each_byte` returns the ascii code `c` for each letters. If a letter is lower case (for example `x`) `122-c` returns `122-120` so `2` that is the position of the corresponding bit. `1<<2` shift to the right the bits of the number 1 and you obtain 100 (binary), then the bitwise operator `|` (OR) with res gives `0 | 100 = 100` so `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 00` (without spaces and with leading zeros added).

Advantage: the string is parsed only once, there's no need to create an array and you only need one string manipulation (the formatted string at the end). The algorithm only uses operations that a processor is able to do very quickly.

Notices:

This code is able to deal with utf8 strings without modification since multibyte characters don't use values under 80 (Hex).

For better performances, you can replace the `between?(...,...)` method with simple number comparaisons:

```
res |= c>96 ? c<123 ? 1<<(122-c) : 0 : c<91 ? c>64 ? 1<<(90-c) : 0 : 0
```

With this change, this code is at least 2X faster than your second way.